# what is the telescopic retinal illuminance of a star?

Tags: astronomy, stars, telescopes, luminosity

What is the retinal illuminance (in trolands) or luminance (in $cd/m^2$) of a star image viewed through a telescope?

I'm looking for a formula that will calculate this value for input values of star illuminance and some combination of telescope aperture, numerical aperture, focal length, magnification and/or exit pupil.

This answer is necessary to compare the astronomer's illuminance values to the human visual research in resolution, contrast and flicker sensitivity functions at what are probably low mesopic and scotopic (not foveal) stimulus intensities in double star astronomy.

As baseline values, the illuminance of a 0 magnitude star (vega) is about $2.4E-06$ lux, and the area of a 250 mm aperture, which is fully illuminated by the source, is about 490 $cm^2$. The angular extent of a diffracted star image, at a magnification equal to the aperture, is about 4 arc minutes on the retina.

The fully illuminated aperture and the diffracted image are finite areas, not "point sources". In particular, I am unsure what role magnification and/or exit pupil play in reducing the apparent brightness of the star.

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 4) If you get a satisfactory answer, remember to accept it by clicking on the green checkmark.